# Null Coalesce Operator and SQL IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, in-clause

My homepage is displaying a table with different data taken from a DB based on the current user's team. I am creating a cookie with the team when the user logs in which I am reading when displaying the table.

When the user is not logged-in, I also want to display the table, but I want it to show the data for 2 (or more) teams. I am using a temporary solution for now using the null coalesce operator which defaults to the first team and looks like this: `$team = $_COOKIE ['team'] ?? 1;`

And my query: `$associates = "SELECT associate_id, first_name, last_name FROM scp.associates WHERE team = '$team' ORDER BY associate_id ASC";`

Is there any way to modify either or both of these to get my desired output? So far, I have tried the following:

```
$team = $_COOKIE ['team'] ?? '1, 2';
$associates = "SELECT associate_id, first_name, last_name FROM scp.associates
    WHERE team IN ('$team') ORDER BY team ASC, associate_id ASC";
```

which works if the cookie is set and:

```
$team = $_COOKIE ['team'] ?? "'1', '2'";
$associates = "SELECT associate_id, first_name, last_name FROM scp.associates
    WHERE team IN ($team) ORDER BY team ASC, associate_id ASC";
```

which works when the cookie is not set... I have tried other variations of these, but could not get it to work. Any ideas? Thanks!

**Edit**: My cookie is a string and I am now using prepared statements. The new code looks like this:

```
$team = $_COOKIE['team'] ?? '1';
$associates = "SELECT associate_id, first_name, last_name FROM scp.associates
    WHERE team IN (?) ORDER BY team ASC, associate_id ASC";
$res_associates = odbc_prepare ( $conn, $associates );
odbc_execute ( $res_associates, array ( $team ) );
```

When I change to `'1, 2'`, I am getting no results from the DB. My `if ( odbc_num_rows ( $res_associates ) > 0 )` is false.

**Edit2**: When I add the values directly in my query, it works but when it takes them from the variable (either prepared or not) it doesn't...

So this works:

```
$associates = "SELECT associate_id, first_name, last_name FROM scp.associates
    WHERE team IN ('1', '2') ORDER BY team ASC, associate_id ASC";
```

But this does not:

```
$team = $_COOKIE['team'] ?? " '1', '2'";
$associates = "SELECT associate_id, first_name, last_name FROM scp.associates
    WHERE team IN (?) ORDER BY team ASC, associate_id ASC";
```

(the space between " and ' is needed so it doesn't think it's a file)

**Solution**:

```
$team = $_COOKIE['team'] ?? '1,2';
$terms = explode ( ',', $team );
$placeholders = rtrim ( str_repeat ( '?, ', count ( $terms ) ), ', ' );

$associates = "SELECT associate_id, first_name, last_name FROM scp.associates
    WHERE team IN ($placeholders) ORDER BY team ASC, associate_id ASC";

$res_associates = odbc_prepare ( $conn, $associates );
odbc_execute ( $res_associates, $terms );
```

Comment: just to make sure, what version of php are you using?

Comment: I am running WAMP with PHP version 7.0.3

Comment: I assume by parameterize you mean prepared statements. I am aware of this and currently in the process of updating everything. As for your suggestions, I can't say I am sure what you mean. Can you expand or provide an example? Thanks!

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($COOKIE['team'])` ?

Comment: It shows `string '1' (length=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split on a `,`s, put placeholders into your query, and then bind each term.

Something like (I assume you're using PDO, if not empty the `execute` call and use the appropriate call for your driver) this would do it:

```
$team = $_COOKIE['team'] ?? '1, 2';
$terms = explode(',', $team);
$placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($terms)), ', ');
$associates = "SELECT associate_id, first_name, last_name 
               FROM scp.associates 
               WHERE team IN ($placeholders) 
               ORDER BY team ASC, associate_id ASC";
$get_stuff = $pdo->prepare($associates);
$get_stuff->execute($terms));
```

Rough demo: https://3v4l.org/REqPc

Comment: I modified your solution for use with `odbc`, but I am getting no results from my DB.

`$associates = "SELECT associate_id, first_name, last_name FROM scp.associates WHERE team IN (?) ORDER BY team ASC, associate_id ASC";

$res_associates = odbc_prepare ( $conn, $associates );
odbc_execute ( $res_associates, array ( $placeholders ) );`

My `if ( odbc_num_rows ( $res_associates ) > 0 )` is false.

Comment: `$placeholders ` goes in the query, `$terms` is the array of values and needs to be bound.

Comment: `$placeholders` IS going in the query, it's replacing the `?`.

Comment: Yes, that should be correct. Was that a question or what you are doing? You commented code doesn't have that.

Comment: It's there :) I just didn't add the `$team, $terms and $placeholders` to my comment for brevity.

Comment: `Can you put in your `prepare` and `execute` lines?  If `odbc_execute ($res_associates, array ($placeholders));` is your actual code that should be `odbc_execute ($res_associates, $terms);`

Comment: Okay, I just realized what it does and how I should be using it... and I got it to work! I had to change it to `'1,2'` (without space). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a type issue, couple things to ask when solving this type of problem. What type is `$_COOKIE ['team']`? and what type is `team` in the database?

Option 1: I think PHP probably thinks `$_COOKIE ['team']` is an int when it should be a string, and it needs quotes. So you could do something like this which implicitly casts it to a string and adds quotes:

`$team = $_COOKIE ['team'] ? "'" . $_COOKIE ['team'] . "'" :  "'1', '2'";`

Option 2: Add quotes in the query as in the first one
`WHERE team IN ('$team')`
and then merely cast it to a string.

`$team = $_COOKIE ['team'] ? (string) $_COOKIE ['team'] : '1, 2';`

Comment: I agree that this is likely a type issue, that's why I was playing around with quotes. In the DB, `team` is varchar(50) so I assumed the cookie would also be a string. I will try your exact code, even though I already tried casting it to a string. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting a `Notice: Undefined index: team` on both of your solutions when the cookie is not set.

Comment: Depending on warning level that'll happen, try starting the expression with
`$team = isset($_COOKIE ['team'])` instead